# Converting int to escaped octal character

Tags: ruby, int, type-conversion, octal

Given an integer - say, `x=20`, I'd like to convert this into a string containing its escaped octal character. I.e. ...

```
x=20

# y = ... Some magic

p y # => "\024"
```

The closest I've managed to get is by using:

```
x.to_s(8) # => "24"
```

However, I'm completely stumpted on how to convert this string into an escaped octal character! Any ideas, internet?

Comment: `"\024".b` is represented as `"\x14"`, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Ok, so how can I convert 20 into "\x14"? Again, I only know how to convert it into "14".

Comment: And I am trying to do some low-level packet manipulation, which requires me to input certain fields as their escaped octal values.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Low level usually requires binary values.

Comment: I am using packetfu, which (due to its implementation) requires me to use an octal value here.... But anyway, I really don't see how my application is relevant!

Comment: It's often easier to help when some context is provided.

Comment: I believe your question is confusing people because you don't *really* want to *"convert this into a string containing its escaped octal character"*, which implies you want to end up with the *four-character string* `'\024'`. I think you want an unescaped string containing the *single character* at codepoint (decimal) 20, which is simply `20.chr` or `x.chr` in this case. It is crude in the extreme to fiddle with `Array#pack` to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Kernel#sprintf` to format the number.

Like this

```
x = 20
y = sprintf('\%03o', x)

puts y
```

**output**

```
\024
```

---

**Update**

Maybe I misunderstood you. If you just want a character with the given code point then just use `Integer#chr`.

Like this

```
x = 20
y = x.chr

p y
```

**output**

```
"\x14"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-pack):

```
[20].pack("C")  #=> "\x14"
```

Comment: It is just perverse to use `pack` and `unpack` to emulate the functionality of tailor-made methods like `Integer#chr` and `String#split`.

Comment: I've suggested `pack` because the OP wants to do "low level" operations.

Answer (score -1):

```
x = 20

y = '\%03o' % x

puts y
```

If you use *p* to display *y* you would see 2 backslashes as *p* outputs ruby parsable strings.

Comment: As the top answer thankfully noticed, my naive younger self didn't really specify this question accurately: The single backslash in my desired output was not a mistake; I really did want `"\024"`.

Comment: As I now know, the correct answer is just to use `x.chr` - or, a more "general" solution to the problem (should you ever need it) is to (with caution!) do: `eval "?\\#{x.to_s(8)}"`, or `eval "?\\x#{x.to_s(16)}"`.